# Why can’t Haskell deduce this type

Tags: haskell, algebra, type-variables

I have been trying to writing a program to implement polynomials on arbitrary field, a mathematical structure. I chose Haskell as the programming language, and I used the `GADTs` language extension. However, I don’t understand why GHCi can’t deduce the constraints of `a`.

The context:

```
-- irreducible.hs

{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

infixl 6 .+
infixl 7 .*

class Ring a where
  (.+) :: a -> a -> a
  (.*) :: a -> a -> a
  fneg :: a -> a
  fzero :: a
  funit :: a

class (Ring a) => Field a where
  finv :: a -> a

data Polynomial a where 
  Polynomial :: (Field a) => [a] -> Char -> Polynomial a

instance (Show a) => Show (Polynomial a) where
  show (Polynomial (a0:ar) x)
    = show a0
      ++ concatMap (\(a, k) -> "+" ++ show a ++ x:'^':show k) (zip ar [0..])
  show (Polynomial [] _) = show (fzero::a)
```

Explanation: A ring is something with addition and multiplication defined, where addition forms an (actually abelian) group, and multiplication forms a monoid. A field is a ring with the inverse of multiplication defined. The polynomials on a field is represented by a list of coefficients and a character. The character, for example `'x'`, indicates this polynomial is about the unknown variable `x`. For the zero polynomial, which is written as `Polynomial [] 'x'`, I want it shows the zero element of the underlying field.

After running on GHCi, I got this:

```
irreducible.hs:59:28: error:
    • Could not deduce (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘show’
      from the context: Show a
        bound by the instance declaration at irreducible.hs:55:10-40
      or from: Field a
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Polynomial :: forall a. Field a => [a] -> Char -> Polynomial a,
                 in an equation for ‘show’
        at irreducible.hs:59:9-23
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 25 others
        ...plus 87 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: show (fzero :: a)
      In an equation for ‘show’:
          show (Polynomial [] _) = show (fzero :: a)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Polynomial a)’
   |
59 |   show (Polynomial [] _) = show (fzero::a)
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

irreducible.hs:59:34: error:
    • Could not deduce (Ring a1) arising from a use of ‘fzero’
      from the context: Show a
        bound by the instance declaration at irreducible.hs:55:10-40
      or from: Field a
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Polynomial :: forall a. Field a => [a] -> Char -> Polynomial a,
                 in an equation for ‘show’
        at irreducible.hs:59:9-23
      Possible fix:
        add (Ring a1) to the context of
          an expression type signature:
            forall a1. a1
    • In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘(fzero :: a)’
      In the expression: show (fzero :: a)
      In an equation for ‘show’:
          show (Polynomial [] _) = show (fzero :: a)
   |
59 |   show (Polynomial [] _) = show (fzero::a)
   |
```

Now let’s focus on the questionable part:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Polynomial a) where
  show (Polynomial (a0:ar) x) = show a0 ++ [...]
  show (Polynomial [] _) = show (fzero::a)
```

In my opinion, `Polynomial a` guarantees `a` is an instance of `Field`, which implies `a` is an instance of `Ring`. So calling `fzero::a`, just like `42::Int`, should be reasonable. Besides, I already wrote `Show a` as a constraint, and the constructor of `Polynomial a` has the shape `Polynomial [a] Char`, so it should also know the type of `a0` is an instance of `Show`.

Apparently, the interpreter thinks differently. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Common mistake, search for `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: @arrowd Thanks! That works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From arrowd's comment:*

The code is fine, but requires the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, which makes the type variable `a` in `fzero :: a` refer to the previously introduced `a`.